# How to safely eject a volume when the icon has disappeared?

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, mount, eject

I was using an external hard drive and the icon has disappeared (the program used to mount the volume hung so I stopped the process with `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk3`) - so now I do not know how to safely eject it. It's an old external hard disk, and I can feel it spinning when I put my hand on it, so I don't want to take any risks.

Comment: Does it show up in **Disk Utility**? If it does, eject it and if not, then it's safe to unplug.

Comment: If you unmounted all the partitions, you can just unplug it. The potential for damage is when it's still mounted and being written to.

Comment: @user3439894 please make that an answer. It has saved me several times over the past day. Including right now, when traditional right click -> Eject worked, yet the disk was still physically spinning (I could feel/hear it!). Doing as you suggested and opening Disk Utility, right clicking on the external volume in question and clicking 'Eject' there worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a *disk* has been ejected via **Finder** and the icon has disappeared but you feel it hasn't yet, then here are some things you can try:

- Does it show up in Disk Utility? If it does, eject it from there and if not, then it's safe to unplug.
- In **Terminal**, `diskutil list` -- It the device is not listed then it's safe to unplug it. If it is listed use e.g. `diskutil eject diskN` where `diskN` is e.g. `disk3`, then follow it up with `diskutil unmountDisk diskN`.  If it doesn't unmount you can use: `diskutil unmountDisk force diskN`